# visualization for high-dimensional points in R

Tags: r, visualization

I have a centroid, e.g., A. and I have other 100 points. All of these points are of high-dimensions, e.g, 1000 dimensions. Is there a way to visualize these points in a two-dimensional space in-terms of their distance with A.

Comment: It is helpful to provide a sample data set and/or code that you've tried.  Also, to me, your explanation is a bit vague and could use some clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common (though simple) way to visualize high-dimensional points in low dimensional space is to use some form of [multi-dimensional scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling):

```
dat <- matrix(runif(1000*99),99,1000)
#Combine with "special" point
dat <- rbind(rep(0.1,1000),dat)

out <- cmdscale(dist(dat),k = 2)

#Plot everything, highlighting our "special" point
plot(out)
points(out[1,1],out[1,2],col = "red")
```

[image]

You can also check out `isoMDS` or `sammon` in the **MASS** package for other implementations in R.

Comment: thanks, joran. But can you let me know why (out[1,1], out[1,2]) is the point that is appended? Is that a specification in cmdscale, i.e., the appened data will be out at the head of output?

Comment: @user288609 There's nothing special going on here. It's just outputting the 2D coords in the same order you provided the points in. I arbitrarily designated the first row of `dat` as my "special" point, but you could use any row you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The distance (by which I assume you mean the norm of the difference vector) is only 1 value, so you can calculate these norms and show them on a 1D plot, but for 2D you'll need a second parameter.